# My application shows nothing except a black screen

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, freeze, delphi-xe5

Hy, my first Android application generates a number based on a key provided by the user, so it has 2 editboxes and a little code. It is working on all Android 4.x devices I've tested, except the person's tablet I made the aplication for. It doesn show anything, just a black screen. It's an **Android 4.2**, Cortex A7, 1,2GHz QUAD Core tablet.

I've put a ShowMessage dialog in the Main Windows's "OnPaint" event and it shows it on runtime, I click "Ok", but the screen stays black and after a minute or so if I touch "Back" I get "Application is not responding". On my Android phone, if I run my application, it keeps showing the ShowMessage dialog as the main windows is redrawn, but it's working fine.

I don't know how to find the problem if I don't have an error.

I am working on **Delphi XE5 Update 2**. Thanks, The code is below:

```
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  IdGlobal, IdHash, IdHashMessageDigest, FMX.Edit;

type
  TMainWindow = class(TForm)
    Label1Key: TLabel;
    Key: TEdit;
    numar: TEdit;
    LabelNumber: TLabel;
    PanelCentrare: TPanel;
    procedure KeyChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure codChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure KeyTyping(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MessagePaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
      const ARect: TRectF);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  function MD5(S: String): String; overload;

  var
  MainWindow: TMainWindow;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

function MD5(S: String): String;
begin
  with TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create do
  begin
    Result := AnsiLowerCase(HashStringAsHex(S));
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainWindow.KeyChange(Sender: TObject);
var personalkey, md5string,ascii :string;
begin
  personalkey := Uppercase(key.Text);
  if length(personalkey) = 6 then
    begin
      md5string:= Uppercase(MD5(lowercase(personalkey)));
      ascii := inttostr(ord(md5string[1]))+inttostr(ord(md5string[2]))+inttostr(ord(md5string[3]));
      numar.Text := ascii;
     end
end;


procedure TMainWindow.KeyTyping(Sender: TObject);
begin
  key.MaxLength := 6;
end;

procedure TMainWindow.MessagePaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
  //ShowMessage('Window Paint.');
end;

procedure TMainWindow.codChange(Sender: TObject);
var  personalkey, md5string, ascii :string;
begin
  personalkey := Uppercase(key.Text);
  if length(personalkey) = 6 then
        begin
            md5string:= Uppercase(MD5(lowercase(personalkey)));
            ascii := inttostr(ord(md5string[1]))+inttostr(ord(md5string[2]))+inttostr(ord(md5string[3]));
            numar.Text := ascii;
    end
end;

end.
```

Comment: A little code could help, thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to find the problem if I don't have a CODE.

Comment: As the others say, it must be somewhere in your code. Try to reduce your code as much as possible, so you get a so called SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/) which still displays the problem, and show the exact code you have.

Comment: My Guess is that this persons tablet's CPU does not have the minimum requirements for FireMonky: Armv7 with NEON support. There are Android apps out there that can check this

Comment: As @whosrdaddy says, check the device. Google Play has a free app called "CPU Identifier" that will check the capabilities of the GPU and CPU to see if it meets the requirements for FMX mobile.

Comment: @user3665067 Search for FMX in the google play store, you will find at least 2 free applications that demonstrates Firemonkey. This is what I use to test, not all androids works.

Comment: Hy, because no other Delphi apk runs on this tablet("CPU Identifier" says Cortex A7 with Neon support thanks @KenWhite) I tested another tablet(with Neon support) from the same company - Allview , and the result is: black screen before GUI. With "Delphi FireMonkey Sample+AD" from Google Play I get the same black screen(thanks @eelias). 
I passed the problem to Allview's Support and they keep telling me that my apk or DelphiFireMonkeySample+AD doesn't have all the needed Libraries and they need a full application. Are they asking for something I don't understand or just delaying? Thank you all!